# Django bulk_create is slow

Tags: python, django

I am trying to benchmark using bulk_create for a different project, and finding it to be slower than I like.  I am running the below, and seeing that bulk_create can take a minute per day.  [This](http://voorloopnul.com/blog/doing-bulk-update-and-bulk-create-with-django-orm/) example quotes 1/2s for 10K objects, so I am surprised that something 5x as big would take 20x as long.  Is there any way to make this faster?

```
import requests
import random
from fake_model.models import FakeNode, FakeStation, FakePrice, FakeWeather
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

#Make a word list
word_site = "http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/linuxwords"
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()


def random_name(WORDS):
    name = "{0}-{1}".format(
        random.choice(WORDS).title(),
        random.choice(WORDS).title()
    )
    if len(name) < 100:
        return name
    else:
        return random_name(WORDS)

print "Deleting"
FakeNode.objects.all().delete()
FakeStation.objects.all().delete()

FakePrice.objects.all().delete()
FakeWeather.objects.all().delete()

print "Prepping"
node_list = [FakeNode(name=random_name(WORDS)) for x in range(0, 1000)]
station_list = [FakeStation(name=random_name(WORDS)) for x in range(0, 1000)]

print "Making"
FakeNode.objects.bulk_create(node_list)
FakeStation.objects.bulk_create(station_list)

start_date = datetime(2012, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime(2012, 1, 2)


def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

print "@profile"


@profile
def make():
    price_list = []
    temp_list = []
    nodes = FakeNode.objects.all()
    stations = FakeStation.objects.all()
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        price_list = [
            FakePrice(
                node=node,
                dt=single_date,
                hr=hr,
                price=randint(0, 1000)
            )
            for node in nodes for hr in range(1, 25)
        ]
        temp_list = [
            FakeWeather(
                station=station,
                dt=single_date,
                hr=hr,
                temp=randint(0, 1000)
            )
            for station in stations for hr in range(1, 25)
        ]

        print single_date
        c = FakePrice.objects.bulk_create(price_list)
        c = FakeWeather.objects.bulk_create(temp_list)

make()
from django.db.models import Count
print FakePrice.objects.all().aggregate(Count('id'))
```

Timing:

```
Total time: 13.8182 s
File: generate.py
Function: make at line 49

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    49                                           @profile
    50                                           def make():
    51         1            4      4.0      0.0      price_list = []
    52         1            2      2.0      0.0      temp_list = []
    53         1          221    221.0      0.0      nodes = FakeNode.objects.all()
    54         1          146    146.0      0.0      stations = FakeStation.objects.all()
    55         2           65     32.5      0.0      for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    56                                                   price_list = [
    57         1            3      3.0      0.0              FakePrice(
    58                                                           node=node,
    59                                                           dt=single_date,
    60                                                           hr=hr,
    61                                                           price=randint(0, 1000)
    62                                                       )
    63     25001      3373017    134.9     24.4              for node in nodes for hr in range(1, 25)
    64                                                   ]
    65                                                   temp_list = [
    66         1            2      2.0      0.0              FakeWeather(
    67                                                           station=station,
    68                                                           dt=single_date,
    69                                                           hr=hr,
    70                                                           temp=randint(0, 1000)
    71                                                       )
    72     25001      3463471    138.5     25.1              for station in stations for hr in range(1, 25)
    73                                                   ]
    74                                           
    75         1           70     70.0      0.0          print single_date
    76         1      3526035 3526035.0     25.5          c = FakePrice.objects.bulk_create(price_list)
    77         1      3455148 3455148.0     25.0          c = FakeWeather.objects.bulk_create(temp_list)
```

Comment: What are you using for this timing output I'm seeing here?  It looks extremely helpful.

Comment: [Line profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler).  It is pretty sweet.

Comment: If it helps you, the invokation with the above code is `kernprof -lv generate.py` .

Comment: Final note: I eventually solved this by refactoring it for a task queue and just using that.  Each day got down to about 3s.